# API to get count of task instance group instances in AWS EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

I want to get the count of task instance groups instances in AWS EMR.

For this, I used Cloudwatch to check heartbeat of each task instance groups instances. But I think, at the end EMR is a framework that uses hadoop, and hadoop's master must have information of live task nodes.

Can anyone please tell me the metadata link(or any file location) to get this information ?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Java tool to dynamically resize an EMR cluster during the processing.  It has some code to get the count of instances in an instance, as part of it.  Maybe this will be what you are looking for.  Check it out at:

http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/dynamically-resize-emr/

The source code is available on Github

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will evaluate this tool. If you allow, I can also contribute in your repository.